# How to find $ P $ such that $ A^\top = PAP^{-1} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A $ be a matrix such that $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R}) $. How to find $ P \in \operatorname{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R})  $, without doing heavy calculus, such that $ A^\top = PAP^{-1} $, where $ A^\top $ is the transpose of the matrix $ A $. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One way is to costruct the Jordan forms $J$ and $J_2$ for $A$ and for $A^t$, and matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $A=CJC^{-1}$ and $A^t=DJD^{-1}$. Then you can take $P=D^{-1}C$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that A is diagonalisable (the algebraic multiplicity of each eigen-value is equal to its geometric multiplicity) then you can find a matrix X (consisting of the eigen-vectors of A) such that:
D = $X^{-1}AX$ where D is a diagonal matrix.
So then A = $XDX^{-1}$.

So $A^{T}$ = $(XDX^{-1})^{T}$ =$(X^{-1})^{T}D^{T}X^{T}$ =$(X^{T})^{-1}DX^{T}$
$$But D =  X^{-1}AX$$
So $A^{T} =Y^{-1}X^{-1}AXY$ where Y = $X^{T}$ so $$A^{T} = (XY)^{-1}AXY$$
So you can take $(XY)^{-1}$ = P